# what is other way to to communicate the struts1.38 to oracle

Tags: java, jdbc, struts-1

can any body explain alternate way to communicate the struts1.x to database oracle

```
public class Myaction extends Action
 {
 public ActionForwards excecute(-,-,-,-)
 {
  //donot write  jdbc code here, where we write this jdbccode
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu would want to use DAO and DTO Design Pattern. You would want to give this [article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/database-interaction-dao-and) a read

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example just to give you an idea. You can create a DAO class and have a method in there that has all the jdbc related stuff, such as getting connection and setting up session. That method in the DAO queries the database and you handle the result in your action class.

You Action class:

```
public class Myaction extends Action
 {
 public ActionForwards excecute(-,-,-,-)
 {
  //donot write  jdbc code here, where we write this jdbccode
   MyDAO dao = new MYDAO();
   Resultset result = dao.getResults();
  }
}
```

DAO class

```
public class MyDAO{
        public ResultSet getResults(){
            private Session session = MyUtil.getSession();
            String query = "SELECT * from MY_TABLE";
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            Connection con = session.connection();
            ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
            return result; 
        }
    }
```